# How can I disable built-in gestures in unity 2d

Tags: unity-2d, gestures

I have a tablet with GMA 500 graphics which totally blows... but the psb-gfx driver does a decent job with 2d acceleration (no 3d though) so I'm stuck using unity 2d. Anyway, I can't disable unity-2d's gestures so I can't configure the gestures I want with ginn (they conflict with the built in ones).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57586/how-can-i-disable-arbitrary-default-multitouch-gestures-in-unity

Comment: You can really look forward to 11.10. Unity 2D has come a very long way.

Comment: @desgua Not a duplicate. The other question refers to unity as a compiz plugin. My question is for unity-2d.

Comment: @Jo-Erlend I just installed 11.10... still can't figure out how to disable the built in touch actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on oneiric with unity 3d this is the same ,the gesture are integrated in unity ,the only way seems to use gnome or lxde ,using touchegg

Comment: answer from utouch develloper https://answers.launchpad.net/utouch/+question/177574

Comment: to adhere to stack overflows guides, the answer from totof's link above is: "Unfortunately, there is no way to change the gesture mapping in Unity at this time with directly modifying the Unity source code."