# Middle-click does nothing but makes window controls appear

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, multi-touch

Just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and noticed that the middle-click (actually three finger-tap on the touchpad) on Firefox doesn't work as it used to. When doing it on a link it doesn't get opened on a new tab, in fact, it doesn't get opened at all. Only the (useless) window size and position controls appear, as demonstrated on terminal in the following screen shot.

[image: Middle-click on terminal]

How do I get my tab-opening middle-clicks back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to open a terminal with:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

and then use the command:

```
synclient TapButton3=2  ClickFinger3=2
```

This disables Unity's use of 3 tap and 3 click (for click devices) gestures. See [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/754000), in particular comments around #68, and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/971783) if the above doesn't work.

Comment: The setting doesn't persist between restarts, so as advised [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/971783/comments/10) I added the command to startup applications.

Comment: On suspend the `TapButton3` setting resets to 0. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please see this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/140489/how-to-edit-synaptics-configuration-xorg-conf-way-doesent-work/148746#148746 .

Comment: and how to still have the window control with 4 fingers? (4 fingers to open the dash is pointless, since the FLAG key does that and your hand have to be ready to type right after... but opening the window controls would be neat)