# Workspace Switcher source code

Tags: 14.04, source-code, workspace-switcher

Which package source code do I need to get to see the code responsible for the workspace switching?

Specifically when I select an open application on the launcher and it switches to the workspace it's on.

Comment: [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/247340/455543)