# Touchegg not working 12.10 after multi-touch unity gestures disabled

Tags: multi-touch, touchegg

I've read the thread here [How can I disable arbitrary default multitouch gestures in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57586/how-can-i-disable-arbitrary-default-multitouch-gestures-in-unity/90383#90383) where people seem to have solved their problems with touchegg in 12.10.

As for me, I'm able to install everything without errors but then when I bring up touchegg none of the gestures are recognized.

Two questions:

Do I need to get utouch installed?  It is not a recognized package for 12.10.

When I run dpkg-buildpackage I have to use sudo.  Could this affect the process?  Should I get fakeroot?

p.s. I know my touchpad at least supports 3-finger gestures because I have used them with windows 8.

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I have been looking for a fix myself to no avail so far.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  It's kind of driving me crazy actually.  If you do find a solution please let me know.

Comment: any ideas with this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable the synclient links with
synclient TapButton2=0 
synclient TapButton3=0 
synclient ClickFinger2=0 
synclient ClickFinger3=0 
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0 
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0

Comment: I tried doing that and it disabled my ability to scroll with two fingers etc. but when I launch touchegg is still doesn't recognize any of my gestures.  It seems like something isn't working right.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working to my liking. I have a desktop with Ubuntu 14.04.2 and Unity 7.2.5 with an [Apple Magic Trackpad](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XIJ3MW) (and a [bluetooth USB adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007Q45EF4)). Hardware setup was basically seamless (easy, no drivers/etc, had a little trouble pairing at first, must hold the button down, no trouble since).

My problem was that touchegg and ginn could only be used for 4-finger gestures (Unity blocks or interferes with 2, 3, and 4-finger gestures). I've read using Gnome Desktop could solve the issue, but I'm used to (and already setup with) Unity. I wanted Unity's 2-finger gestures (horiz and vert scrolling), and fully configurable 3 and 4 finger gestures (for workspace switching, etc -- I'll update once I have my full set of gestures worked out.)

(Note I had previously followed xSwipe setup instructions [here](http://blog.mpiannucci.com/view/multitouchgesture), didn't fully work, hopefully this didn't taint my setup.)

Here's what I did:

1. Disable unity gestures as described in the referenced question ([updated answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/205045/159633)), recompile, restart. (This may not have been necessary, try first without.)
2. May have to dis/enable bluetooth trackpad
3. Run the referenced commands in the [touchegg FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/FAQ) to disable synclient's use of 3 and 4 finger gestures (but leave horiz and vert scrolling):

Commands:

```
  synclient TapButton2=0
  synclient TapButton3=0
  synclient ClickFinger2=0
  synclient ClickFinger3=0
  synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
  synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
```

I will likely place these commands in my `~/.xinitrc` as described in [other questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290009/how-do-i-make-my-synclient-settings-stick-ubuntu-13-04).

I do notice that I still can't customize 2-finger gestures (even with horiz/vert disabled), but that's ok for me (for now), I like the default horiz/vert scrolling. Maybe sometime I'll want 2-finger pinch or something, but not yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have 14.04 with unity and was tried a lot to install touchegg, which I couldn't. But I've found an alternative solution, it is [xSwipe](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe).

It's a little bit tiring that editing a text formatted configuration file to find the righteous shortcuts, but after at all, it worths.

It works with unity!