# Touchscreen on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, thinkpad, multi-touch, touchscreen

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my thinkpad yoga, and touch worked out of the box (Thank you devs). But I can't figure out how to configure more gestures.

Does anyone know what software is being used by default?

I've seen on some posts there's some hardcoded gestures in Unity. Is this getting in the way of ginn/others to capture the touchevents? Can anyone clarify? How can I make sure I am in control of the gestures?

Comment: **Note:** The *ubuntu-touch* tag is ONLY for tablet/phone development branch (for the moment).

Comment: Ah, Yeah. I noticed it's really hard to find any information about multitouch/touch on laptops, since ubuntu called it's phone os touch :S

Comment: Try **touchscreen** related questions.

Comment: Appearantly ginn has been broken for 2 years? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ginn/+bug/985121
This is the issue I'm encountering

Comment: And unfortunately the *touch/gesture* code experts are focused on **Ubuntu Touch** for the next few weeks/months (until *ubuntu-rtm* build is shipped).

Answer (score 1):

So the status of touch on laptops is that Ubuntu ships with hardcoded gestures in 14.04.

I've disabled the gestures as described in this post: [Disable unity gestures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57586/how-can-i-disable-arbitrary-default-multitouch-gestures-in-unity). But it requires building unity.