# Touchpad gestures and Touchscreen gestures

Tags: unity, touchpad, touchscreen, gestures, touchegg

Is possible to have gestures for touchpad and touchscreen at the same time?

So far I was only able to enable gestures for touchscreen (using touchegg), after disabling unity default multitouch gestures (see here: [How can I disable arbitrary default multitouch gestures in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57586/how-can-i-disable-arbitrary-default-multitouch-gestures-in-unity/205045#205045)). The problem is that touchegg only recognizes the input from touchscreen and not from touchpad.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 (updated a few days ago, had the same problems with 14.04) my laptop is a Dell XPS 15 9530 with touchscreen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about **Unity**, but this is built into **Gnome 3.14** and above:

- https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.14/touchscreen-gestures.html.en[1](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.14/touchscreen-gestures.html.en)

  - I am using 3.18 at the time of writing this.
  - For Unity you can read this, there are these two programs [EasyStroke](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easystroke/) and [Gesture Injector](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ginn/) - I have never used these, I would try EasyStroke first.