# Alt-Tab Menu coming up randomly

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, trackpad

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a macbook pro. I'm almost certain it has something to do with the trackpad; I know a double tap with three fingers activates it by default, but I'm pretty sure it's popping up even when I'm not doing this. Is there a way to disable it in relation to trackpad gestures, or maybe an extensive list somewhere of gestures that exist, so I know what to avoid? While I'm asking though, is there any way to set/disable/create gestures for the trackpad? There doesn't seem to be anything in default settings.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57586/how-can-i-disable-arbitrary-default-multitouch-gestures-in-unity